# Error log: upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) on Nginx

Tags: nginx

Olá, eu uso o nginx no Ubuntu 14.04

E o meu script em php só está carregando e não abre! Depois de muito tempo apenas carregando a página, eu dou de cara com essa mensagem:

---

```
An error occurred.

Sorry, the page you are looking for is currently unavailable.
Please try again later.

If you are the system administrator of this resource then you should check the error log for details.

Faithfully yours, nginx.
```

---

Eu fui ver o error.log nesse caminho:

> **/var/log/nginx/nginx_error.log**

e me mostra a seguinte mensagem:

---

```
[error] 2019#0: *1 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) 
    while reading response header from upstream, 
    client: x.x.x.x, server: localhost, request: "GET /sistema-10-reais/ HTTP/1.1", 
    upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock", 
    host: "x.x.x.x.x"
root@meusistema:/var/log/nginx#
```

---

Onde é x.x.x.x é o meu IP.